# SSL/TLS certificate exchange/renewal needs private key of the old certificate in CSR

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, tls1.2, renewal

i am wondering how the certificate renewal works and what is best practise. Let's imagine that i have a device which has private key and certificate (public key) signed by CA. Once the renewal of the certificate is needed, does the device just generates a new pair of private and public key and send a new CSR to CA or does this CSR require also public key of the certificate that is going to be changed?

The use case is not to use the old pair of private and public key but to always use new pair of private and public key. The question is if this new public key signed by private key and send by CSR has to be signed by the old private key also as an additional level of authentication of the device.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

I am trying to find the answer on the Google but haven't found exact answer yet. I am still googling but i would like to increase my chance to get some answers or opinions on this topic.

Comment: In short: Both options are possble: you can get a new certificate with the same key or with a different key.

Comment: thank you but the use case is bit different, it should be new certificate (public key) which is signed by the corresponding private key and also old private key to proof that the old certificate can be removed.

Comment: Authentication at the CA for certificate creation is (usually) not done using the private key of the previous certificate. There is some kind of account involved. Exact details depend on the specific CA.

Comment: As a third option, you can just resubmit the original CSR just before the old certificate expires. I’ve been doing that for years. In any case the contents of a CSR are already designed. You don’t get to redesign the CSR, or the signing process.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! So if i understand it well there are two options as a best practise, either new certificate or extending the old one keeping same keys. Another signature from the old key is not needed and usually not used. May i have a last question? Is this described in some standard or recommendation like RFC or ITUT? Thanks a lot!